# Wait in Node.js before return

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting an error while trying to return from a nested function in javascript. I want to wait for the execution of `YD.on("finished", async function (err, done) {return done;});` before executing `return ('complete');`. But it not waiting. Can anybody help me with this please. Thank you in advance.

```
async function downloadVideo(videoID) {

  let YD = new YoutubeMp3Downloader({
    ffmpegPath: "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg",
    outputPath: "./public/assets/",
    youtubeVideoQuality: "lowest",
    queueParallelism: 2,
    progressTimeout: 2000,
  });


  YD.download(videoID, `${videoID}.mp3`);

  YD.on("finished", async function (err, done) {return done;});

  return ('complete');

}

downloadVideo("lTTajzrSkCw");
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that YD.on(...) is an async function annd that you should await it. Try:

```
await YD.on("finished", async function (err, done) {return done;});
return ('complete');
```

Comment: This is highly unlikely.  Usually a function either accepts a callback OR returns a promise, not both.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap both the `download` function and the event listener `finished` on a Promise:

```
const downloadPromise = (videoID) => { 
      let YD = new YoutubeMp3Downloader({
           ffmpegPath: "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg",
           outputPath: "./public/assets/",
           youtubeVideoQuality: "lowest",
           queueParallelism: 2,
           progressTimeout: 2000,
      });

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         YD.download(videoID, `${videoID}.mp3`);

         YD.on("finished", function (err, done) {
                 resolve(done);
               })
      })
}
```

You should be able to `await` your `downloadPromise` function:

```
async function downloadVideo(videoID) {

  await downloadPromise(videoId)

  return ('complete');

}
```